# Как делать анимацию, в плагине just-validate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, just-validate

Всплывающая ошибка отображается резко, без анимации. Стандартные css свойства анимирования не срабатывают.

[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно анимировать ошибку?

Comment: Код и стили укажите текстом, а не скрином

Comment: @jenya1995 Можете показать верстку и js если есть. Не скрином

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте transition для ваших input полей и для надписей ошибок добавьте анимацию. Так как эти сообщения появляются динамически нужно заранее повесить анимацию в стилях

```
input,
textarea {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.just-validate-error-label {
  animation: 0.5s fadeIn ease;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 from{opacity: 0;}
 to{opacity: 1;}
}
```